# How to check if multiple column values exists in another array?

Tags: eloquent

I hope I will explain my problem

I have table something like this:

```
id|id_2 (table test)
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
```

now i have array of values (id_2's) [2,3,4].

How to get only id's (from table test) where ALL id_2 columns are in array [2,3,4]?

So, in my example, i need value id=1 because id=2 doesn't have value 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.id) FROM test t WHERE t.id_2 IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT(t2.id_2) FROM test t2);
```

This query would solve your problem.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. Hm, i suppose i didn't write question good. If i have array [2,3,4] than i need to match ALL id_2's with ALL values in array for given id. So, when id is 1 ALL id_2 columns have ALL values from given array but for id=2 NOT ALL id_2's have ALL values from given array.